# What is this RAF biplane, and where was the photo taken (possibly in the 1920s)?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image]

My grandfather is in the middle row. He joined the RAF as a boy entrant in 1920. He served in Iraq 1924-27 and India 1927-29 so I suspect by the uniforms this is from one of those postings.

Answer (score 23):

I believe the plane is an [Airco DH-9A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.9A).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.9A#Interwar_RAF_service

[image]

The location may be Iraq. It looks like the RAF 55(B) Squadron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No._55_Squadron_RAF#Between_the_Wars.

On another picture I think I recognise the dog on the right in your picture (but now a bit older): https://55bomber.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/raf-55b-squadron-hinaidi-iraq/

[image]

Blotto:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was almost simultaneous :-)

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I undeleted my answer after adding stuff on the likely(?) squadron. But I do recognise you were first on the plane.

Comment: Clever to exploit the dog.  I got nowhere looking for its triangular insignia.

Comment: What about the other dog? :-)

Comment: @CJDennis didn't even see the black dog! :O Maybe the rapid movement of the white dog drew my attention.

Answer (score 10):

Airco DH.9A. It served during 1920-1931 in [the Middle East and India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airco_DH.9A#Interwar_RAF_service).

Same prop, prop hub, radiator, wing struts, dihedral, exhaust stacks.

I couldn't identify the thing hanging from the top right wing.  Wikipedia's photo has something else hanging there, shaped more like a tiny dinghy than a fuel tank.

I couldn't identify the "triangular roundel" on the radiator, but it matches the one on the side of the nose and on the wing bottom, in Wikipedia's photo.  It may indicate a theatre of operations.

[image: DH.9A vintage photo]

Comment: I had the same answer but 1 minute later. I concur. :) However, now you also have to provide the location!

Comment: BTW, Wikipedia's first picture shows that same thing hanging from the top wing to the right of the pilot (his right). Whatever it is. Your picture does not. And that triangle sign (in a different location).

Comment: Location: in front of a hangar!  Maybe someone who knows military uniforms (or even names to match to faces) could figure out which airbase this was, and when.

Comment: Thanks all, and top work on the dog identification! My grandfathers service record shows he was with "M Sqdn" Iraq, then 55 Sqdn Iraq so spot on guys, thank you.